# Incompatible types firebase database and database reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO7dC.png)

I've tried to use `FireBaseDatabase` to store data and I've import the `FirebaseDatabase` function, but it keep saying that it's an incompactible types

```
Required: com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
Found: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
```

I'm really confuse that where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write :

```
DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid);
```

Please understand that you can access database using FIrebaseDatabaseReference, and you tried to create an object of FirebaseDatabase. Which you already getting using **FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()**

Or you can go for :

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mUserRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users").child(uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write :
try this code.

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

mDatabase.getRoot().child("users").child("uid").addValueEventListener(new
 ValueEventListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }

        });
```

OR

FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

DatabaseReference mUserRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users").child(uid);

Comment: mDatabase.getRoot().child("users")
Can you please let me know why this is needed, 
mDatabase.child("users") won't work? Is there any significance of using .getRoot() ?

Comment: getRoot() : A reference to the root location of this Firebase Database.
it's not compulsory to write this signature, but it's best practice to write this kind of thing

Comment: Is this a new method for firebase? Because I found the code in a youtube tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly shows that you are trying to create an object of FirebaseDatabase type and trying to assign DatabaseReference of the child node, which is completely of differrent types and gives you an error.
You should try this:

```
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference  = mFirebaseDatabase .getReference().child("users").child(uid);
```

or

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

add the dependencies correctly with respect to Firebase Database

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't import the `DatabaseReference`. You have used `private FirebaseDatabase UsersRef` which cause the error, use this :

```cs
private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
```

After that,

```cs
UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
```